# Unparseable date at offset x

Tags: java, simpledateformat

`2017-08-01T05:08:51.000Z`

I'm trying to parse the above date string using below code. It says unparseable date at offset 23. I can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = format.parse("2017-08-01T05:08:51.000Z");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


  }
```

Comment: Try this: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'. Put an apostrophe around Z.

Comment: Or better, use `X` to mean "ISO-8601 UTC offset" - that way I'd hope it would avoid using the system time zone...

Comment: @Igorovics you should use the X letter, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. 
Yes, so the correct format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`